# How do I run my app on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am attempting to run my app an iOS device but I can't seem to figure it out. The reason I am even trying to run it on an iOS device in the first place is because I received an answer on a previous problem I was having that says I have to run it on a device and can't run it on the iOS simulator. [This is the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087083/linker-error-in-xcode) I am unsure of how to add a deice to run it on because I never had to do it before. I release this is a fairly simple question but I searched this site and Google very hard and was unable to find an answer that I could understand.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You plug it in with the usb cable and then choose the option from the list at the top left of xcode screen.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't figure it out for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to add a few pictures with details but don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: How much do you need? I know I can but don't know when I was able to do so.

Comment: @Buster you need 10 I believe

Answer (score 0):

I'll list it for you in steps.

Step 1) Plug in your iOS Device with a USB Cable.

Step 2) Open up your Xcode Project along with Xcode.

Step 3) At the top, you should see your project's name along with a device. Click on it.

Step 4) You'll see many devices, choose the one that you named your device, or use a simulator.

Step 5) Press the play button!

This should work! Hope it helped!